# writing tests for method that calls methods from same class

Tags: junit, mockito

I have the following class, and I've tested method1 having method2 and method3 mocked. I only test cases like:
* if method2 call is OK then ==> OK
* if method2 throws NotFoundException and method3 returns OK ==> OK
* if method2 throws NotFoundException and method3 throws ServiceException ==> ServiceException is indeed thrown

Is it ok to mock methods method2 and method3 in order to test just the functionality of method1? I've also added separate tests for method2 and method3, so I know they are fully working.

```
class ClassUnderTest {

public void method1() {
  try {
    method2();
  } catch (NotFoundException e) {
    method3()
  }
}

public void method2() throws NotFoundException {
  ...
}

public void method3() throws ServiceException {
  ...
}

}
```

Comment: Partial mocks should be used with caution. It can lead to poor design. In general, you should test the behavior, not implementations. You can find more explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430915/partial-mocks-are-bad-why-exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the granularity you want to give to your tests.

A convention could be just mock methods of other clasees in order to make the test cases easier to be written, but in some situations perhaps you have to write mocks for methods on the same class, for example, if you want to simulate an error in the method2 it is ok to mock it.

Always you should try to keep your tests as easy as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do what you're suggesting, using a Mockito `spy`, which allows you to stub some methods but not others.  However, it's often not the best thing to do.  The reason is this.

Any sort of test of a method should be testing the behaviour of that method - what its outputs are, what its side effects are, and whether there's any special behaviour due to variation in inputs.  Your test really shouldn't care what the implementation of a method is, provided it has the right behaviour.  So even though `method1` calls `method2` and `method3`, it's not a requirement of the class that it has been implemented that way.  So instead of a test that asserts that `method1` calls `method2`, your test for `method1` should not mention `method2` at all - it should merely check that the outputs and/or side effects of `method1` are what they are supposed to be.

It does mean that you might have some duplicated assertions between your tests for `method1` and your tests for `method2`, but balancing that is the fact that your tests will be robust against changes of implementation.